# Loops and tests in sublime text

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, sublimetext3

I am used to create macros in Ultraedit to place comments organized in a certain column, for instance column 90.
For this I created a Macro that searches the end of the line, clears ending spaces if exists and adds spaces to the end of line until it reaches the column 90.
I couldn't find any reference for Sublime text for:
how to check the cursor position,
how to check the character on the cursor position,
how to create a loop.
The idea is to create a macro doing something like

```
go to the end of line
while the column is not the first {
  return one character
  if the character under cursor is space or tab {
    delete the character
  }
  else {
    break
  }
}
if column is before or on column 90 { 
  while the column is before 90 {
    insert space 
  } 
  insert "//" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic is available in Python [plugins](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/plugins/) written using the [Sublime API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html). In particular, you would subclass [`sublime_plugin.TextCommand`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand). There are several thousand packages in [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), many of which are plugins, that you can look to for examples. The documentation links earlier are also very helpful. You can get help on specific issues here, at the [Sublime Text Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/), and on the [Discord server](https://discord.com/channels/280102180189634562/280102180189634562). There are also lots of videos on Youtube - [OdatNurd's channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/nurdz) in particular is great.